# On Hover Listener is not firing up in android

Tags: android, onhover, smart-tv

I am trying to call on hover listener in android. i have image buttons in a `relative layout` and i am making a layout for `Android Smart TV`

**The Issue IS:**

When i use my Bluetooth mouse for navigation, the `OnHoverListener` works fine, but when i use smart tv's remote control, nothing happens. i then checked the `onClickListener` , it worked fine with both Remote control, as well as Bluetooth mouse.

**My Question is:**

How can i make the `onHoverListener`  work with the Tv remote control as well?

Comment: The remote actually does not have a pointer as the mouse, right? It is used as you would cicle with the TAB key on a keyboard, right? (I'm asking because I have not used the remote)

Comment: if both answers are yes, you could try to use the `OnFocusChangeListener` for the remote -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html

Answer (score 0):

```
OnFocusChangeListener()
```

worked for me